# Can't access Web API hosted inside Docker container from external device on same Network

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I've created a default ASP.NET Core 5 Web API through Visual Studio 2019 and have it running inside a Docker container (no https to make this example simple). I am using Windows, but the image is running as a Linux Docker Container. When I run the application from Visual Studio, it is started with Docker Compose. When the application runs I'm able to access it from my browser on the Docker host machine, but I'm not able to access it from another device on the same network.

Below are the files I'm using. You can see that I am exposing port 61234 from `docker-compose.yml`. Assuming my Host IP address is 192.168.1.12, if I were to navigate to `http://192.168.1.12:61234/weatherforecast` from a web browser on the host machine, I get a REST response from the controller. If I access that same endpoint from a different laptop on the same Wi-Fi network, the endpoint is unreachable.

I have validated that the laptop can reach the REST endpoint if the application is not running within a Docker container. For this reason, I don't believe the Windows Firewall is getting in the way.

I've looked at everything I can think of. So my question is: Is there anything else I should look at? I assume I'm missing something simple, but just can't seem to find what that might be.

The only change I made to the C# code generated by Visual Studio is making a `UseUrls()` call when creating the web host builder: `webBuilder.UseUrls("http://*:80").UseStartup<Startup>();`

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file. Note the exposed TCP port and the bridge network:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  webapplication1:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapplication1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApplication1/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "61234:80"
    networks:
      - practice-webapi-network

networks:
  practice-webapi-network:
    driver: bridge
```

And here is the auto-generated `Dockerfile` that Visual Studio created:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj", "WebApplication1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication1"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

One thing I want to point out. I believe I would be able to work around this by changing the network driver to Host instead of Bridge, but I need to use a Bridge network for my application. This is just a proof of concept.

Edit 1: Added missing port to example endpoint

Comment: Your setup looks correct. One thing that I noticed, is that you're missing the port number in the URL you use, but maybe that's just a typo? It should be `http://192.168.1.12:61234/weatherforecast`

Comment: @HansKilian It was a typo. I added it to the question now. Thanks

Comment: do you have a solution for your problem?